# Comparativo en varias tablas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito realizar una consulta en SQL validando lo siguiente:

Tengo una tabla padre que se llama `elemento` y tiene un campo `tipoelemento`, y dos tablas hijas `equipo_computo` y `equipo red`, con los campos `tipoequipocomputo` y `tipoequipored` respectivamente.

Requiero realizar una consulta en la base de datos que valide el tipo de elemento seleccionado. Si el usuario seleccionó el `tipoelemento = equipocomputo` muestre los `tiposdequipodecomputo = "servidor fisico"`. Pero si seleccionó el `tipoelemento = equipored` muestre los registros con `tipoequipored = "Switch LAN"`.

Esta es la consulta que estoy ejecutando:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.ID_ELEMENTO , e.NOMBRE
FROM `pmt_equipos_computo` AS ec, `pmt_elementos` AS e , `pmt_equipos_red` AS er 
WHERE e.ID_TIPOELEMENTO = @@drpTipoDispositivo 
AND (ec.ID_ELEMENTO = e.ID_ELEMENTO OR er.ID_ELEMENTO = e.ID_ELEMENTO) 
AND (ec.ID_TIPOEQUIPOCOMPUTO = '2' OR er.ID_TIPOEQUIPORED = '10' );
```

Pero me trae todos los elementos de acuerdo al tipo de elemento seleccionado. No me está validando que solo sean servidores en el caso de `equipos_computo` o que solo sean Switches en el caso de `equipos de red`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las consultas siempre se complican cuando se usa la notación de join implícita, y más aún cuando las condiciones de join se expresan en conjunto con el operador `OR`.

En lo personal, yo expresaría la consulta diferentemente, dividiendo la lógica en 2 claúsulas `EXISTS` separadas por `OR`:

```
select e.ID_ELEMENTO, e.NOMBRE
  from pmt_elementos e
 where e.ID_TIPOELEMENTO = @@drpTipoDispositivo
   and (exists(select null
                 from pmt_equipos_computo ec
                where e.ID_TIPOELEMENTO = 'equipocomputo' -- ajusta este valor
                  and ec.ID_ELEMENTO = e.ID_ELEMENTO
                  and ec.ID_TIPOEQUIPOCOMPUTO = '2')
     or exists(select null
                 from pmt_equipos_red er
                where e.ID_TIPOELEMENTO = 'equipored' -- ajusta este valor
                  and er.ID_ELEMENTO = e.ID_ELEMENTO
                  and er.ID_TIPOEQUIPORED = '10'))
```

La único es que no conozco los valores precisos que te puede devolver `@@drpTipoDispositivo`. Por eso verás 2 lugares en la consulta anotados con `-- ajusta este valor`. En esos 2 lugares, reemplaza la condición con el valor correcto que corresponde a ese tipo de elemento.

Ahora bien, si es imposible que la tabla `pmt_equipos_computo` tenga registros que se relacionan a elementos de tipo `equipored`, y es imposible también que la tabla `pmt_equipos_red` tenga registros que se relacionan a elementos de tipo `equipocomputo`, lo que tendría mucho sentido, entonces ni siquiera necesitas esas 2 condiciones. Entonces puedes simplificar la consulta de esta manera:

```
select e.ID_ELEMENTO, e.NOMBRE
  from pmt_elementos e
 where e.ID_TIPOELEMENTO = @@drpTipoDispositivo
   and (exists(select null
                 from pmt_equipos_computo ec
                where ec.ID_ELEMENTO = e.ID_ELEMENTO
                  and ec.ID_TIPOEQUIPOCOMPUTO = '2')
     or exists(select null
                 from pmt_equipos_red er
                where er.ID_ELEMENTO = e.ID_ELEMENTO
                  and er.ID_TIPOEQUIPORED = '10'))
```

Comment: Gracias!! era justo lo que necesitaba!!!!